# Name of a function used as a pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, pthreads

I've the function:

```
void *task();
```

and the name task is used as argument in another function:

```
pthread_create(..., task, ...);
```

Is this a special case or it's always true the fact that the name of a function contains its address?

The above argument of the pthread_create should be a pointer:

```
void *(*start_routine)(void*)
```

---

EDIT:

```
void *task()
{
    printf("I am a simple thread.\n");
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Note that your `task()` function is not of the correct type to serve as a thread-start function.  It needs to accept one argument of type `void *`, even if it doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special case - on the contrary! A function name almost always decays to a pointer to a function. The only exception is when it is the operand of `&`, i.e. `&task`, it does not decay to a function pointer, but the `&` **will** convert the function designator to a pointer anyway, thus if `task` designates a function (i.e. it is not a pointer), both `pthread_create(..., task, ...);` and `pthread_create(..., &task, ...);` will work alike.

---

In fact the function call operator can be applied **only** to function pointers:

```
printf("Hello world");
```

takes the function designator `printf` **and** converts it to a pointer to a function, and then calls the function pointed to by this pointer giving it the argument `"Hello world"`.

---

Do note also, that `void *task();` is somewhat incorrect declaration for the pthread function, it should be `void *task(void *);`.

Comment: function call is a function call. Does not have anything in common with pointers. same as `int a; a =5;` needs to know the address of `a` to save it it does not mean that `a` in the assignment is a pointer or something similar.

Comment: @P__J__ whatever, that's what the standard says.

Comment: standard says that the pointer to functions is used when you just call it. Where?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @AnttiHaapala

Comment: @P__J__ http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p1 and http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4

Comment: Hello @AnttiHaapala the syntax void *task(void *); doesn't work, instead void *task(); works. The task function uses only the printf

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi it does, but in a function *definition*, you must *name* the argument: `void *task(void *argument) { ... }`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is my example a special case? So, only if the task function doesn't take any argument, can i write void *task();?